# sun.misc.Unsafe warning

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring security and after login i got strange log with warning of sun.misc.Unsafe

```
2020-10-07 16:01:26,752 INFO [main] [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] - Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
2020-10-07 16:01:30,096 INFO [main] [org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer] - Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) with context path ''
2020-10-07 16:01:30,123 INFO [main] [com.wl.tms.frontend.launch.Application] - Started Application in 19.263 seconds (JVM running for 22.095)
2020-10-07 16:01:33,956 WARN [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] [org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteBufferUtils] - Cannot use direct ByteBuffer cleaner, memory leaking may occur
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Unsafe
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteBufferUtils.<clinit>(ByteBufferUtils.java:47) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketBufferHandler.expand(SocketBufferHandler.java:161) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.processSNI(SecureNioChannel.java:334) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2020-10-07 16:01:34,605 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-07 16:01:34,606 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-10-07 16:01:34,663 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Completed initialization in 57 ms
2020-10-07 16:03:25,677 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate] - Ignoring PartialResultException
2020-10-07 16:03:25,761 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] [com.wl.tms.frontend.security.HttpSecurityConfigurer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$82b12948] - User details: org.springframework.se
```

How to resolve this issue?

Im using sring boot - 2.2.4.RELEASE and a tomcat version - 9.0.30

```
java -version
java version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS
```

Comment: Include the output of `java -version`. Is there a specific reason you're using a old Spring Boot and Tomcat versions instead of the most recent updates?

Comment: We use old versions of Spring Boot and tomcat because it's almost finished project and update bring a lot of problems.

JAVA version added to description

Comment: But if the problem occurs by old version of tomcat and spring, i will have to update

Comment: Include full JVM and platform details. `sun.misc.Unsafe` is proprietary API. It may not be present in your JVM.

Comment: Let me clarify, I don't use anywhere sun.misc. Anyway i will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please describe how to add "Include full JVM and platform details"?

Answer (score 0):

[sun.misc.Unsafe](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe) has been [removed in JDK 11](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/issues/468)

But... Tomcat uses it, so either downgrade your Java version, or find an alternative to Tomcat...